# Call forms methods outside of form code

Tags: visual-c++

I have form application:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    CppWinForm1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

I expect to use this form from outside unit functions that was passed as callback to dll function.

I decided to declare form variable as global :

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    CppWinForm1::MyForm form;


[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

But got error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3145   'form': global or static variable may not have managed type 'CppWinForm1::MyForm'   CppWinForm1     
Error (active)      a variable with static storage duration cannot have a ref class type    CppWinForm1
```

How to call forms methods outside of form code?

Comment: You should think about using modeless form.

Comment: Should I use MFC to build form?